# does Python logging inform a handler when it is removed with removeHandler?

Tags: python, logging

I'm subclassing FileHandler to write a handler that produces correct xml files (meaning, not *while* the program is running, only after finishing).

what I do is:

- create the file,
- write a prologue (a `<Diag>` element opening),
- each log record causes a `<line />` element in the xml
- stop logging means write the `</Diag>` element closer.

it would be nice if the Logger.removeHandler would call some special callback in the handler being removed, but I can't find any.  maybe it's not there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlers are **not** notified when they are added or removed from loggers.  Loggers use handlers, but handlers know nothing about loggers.

However, a handler has a `close()` method that is called at program exit by `logging.shutdown()` (registered with `atexit`), so you can add your logic there.  Just remember to call the base implementation's `close()` to ensure proper housekeeping:

```
class MyHandler(logging.Handler):

    def close(self):
       # Write XML epilog.
       # ...
       super(MyHandler, self).close()
```

Comment: I had already overriden the `close()` but wasn't aware it was already part of the base class.  where did you find this information?  I'm curious what would happens if I call the `logging.shutdown()` by hand...

Comment: @mariotomo: I found it the way I learn the most -- by reading the source code! http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ff7acde0faad/Lib/logging/__init__.py

Comment: @mariotomo: You can also just read the documentation!  For `Handler.close()`: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.close; for `shutdown()`: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.shutdown